# Calling a Function from an 'If' statement

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, if-statement

I am using Python 3, and have encountered an error when trying to call a function from an if statement, the following code is a simplified version of the full code but has the same result and I am wandering how to overcome this and allow the program to run the student() function

```
import sys

def logon():
    print("Welcome, please enter your account type")
    acctype = input()
    if acctype == 'teacher':
        sys.exit()
    elif acctype == 'student':
        student()

logon()


def student():
    print("Please enter your name") 
    name = input()

    print("Please enter your class number")
    classnumber = input()
```

The problem occurs after inputting a the word student, as the error returns

```
NameError: name 'student' is not defined
```

Comment: In future, always include the *full* traceback, not just the last line. That way I would have seen the exact problem much sooner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python runs code from top to bottom. Each `def` line creates a function object and stores that as a global name.

When the `logon()` line is run, the `def logon(): ...` statement has been executed and the function exists. However, the `def student(): ...` statement has not yet been reached, so there is no such function *yet*. So when the `logon()` function tries to call the `student()` function, you get a `NameError` exception.

Move the `logon()` line calling the function to *below* the `def student(): ...` statement.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this is very helpful especially to a student who is new to Python!